# Why aren't there any SCSI drivers for my install of UBUNTU 16.10 on my poweredge 2650

Tags: installation, setup, ubuntu-server, dell-poweredge, scsi

I was gifted a server, and I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.10 on it(dell poweredge 2650) and regardless of if I try to install Debian or Ubuntu I continue to run into the same issue; my scsi drives are not detected by the OS.

I initially tried to troubleshoot, and I verified that the green lights that are on in the front of the server indicate that the drives are online however when i get to the partitioning stage I can't actually partition the drives because they do not show. On dell's website, the newest linux OS they support is redhat 7, and they do not even have support for ubuntu listed.

specifically, I would like to know how I go about getting different distro's onto the server, and how I can get around this issue of seemingly not being able to find drivers. I'm new to configuring servers, and i also understand that my hardware is ancient, but I feel as though there should be a workaround for this and I would really like to get this going so I can learn more about network administration.

Oh, and I also went to the Seagate website to see if i could find OS specific drivers there but that was fruitless as well. I cannot boot from USB on this machine either. The feature was not introduced until a later model came about.

Comment: I have a poweredge 1950 at home and have had no issue installing quite a few different linux distros on it. I even had Qubes installed on it at one point. I don't believe your issue is drivers. Did you setup your RAID configuration before trying to install Linux?

Comment: no. ill double check the bios and give it a shot. what bios do you have. Also, do you see an option to directly enter the bios with f11(just curious)?

Comment: The RAID is configured through its own seperate option; not thru the BIOS. At least that's how it is on mine. I don't remember which BIOS I have offhand. At work right now and the server is at home. I do believe I entered my BIOS with f11, but it was some other fx to enter the RAID configuration on bootup.

Comment: I have no option to configure RAID in my setup menu (f2)

Comment: Sorry I'm of limited help at the moment not being in front of that server

Comment: Nowhere in the boot process do you see it flash with an option to enter RAID configuration?

Comment: no. I had to go into the setup utility, then into embedded devices. I found the raid controller after doing some searching based on your initial response. I'm testing it right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50297/discussion-between-anonymous-and-n8te).

Answer (score -1):

my raid controller was disabled by default... enabling the controller allowed my machine to recognize my drives